# Почему парсится только первый матч

Tags: python, парсер, bs4

Выводит в консоль только первый матч, а хотелось бы побольше. Подскажите как исправить, только начал изучать данную библиотеку.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def main():

    url = 'https://www.gosugamers.net/dota2/matches'
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

    results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'cell', 'id': 'matches'})

    for result in results:
        team1 = result.find('span', attrs={'class':'team-1'}).text
        team2 = result.find('span', attrs={'class':'team-2'}).text
        print(team1 +  'vs' + team2)
    

main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не работает, потому что в переменной `results` у вас находится объект `ResultSet` с всего одним элементом (т.к элементов с `id=="matches"` на странице больше нет), и поэтому проход в цикле `for` по нему происходил в одну итерацию, из-за чего метод `find` возвращал только лишь первое совпадение из целого `div`.

Я заменил метод `find` на метод `find_all` и немного "причесал" вывод, всё получилось.

**Код**:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main():
    url = 'https://www.gosugamers.net/dota2/matches'
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

    results = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'cell', 'id': 'matches'})
    teams1 = [team.text.strip() for team in results.find_all('span', attrs={'class': 'team-1'})]
    teams2 = [team.text.strip() for team in results.find_all('span', attrs={'class': 'team-2'})]
    for teams in zip(teams1, teams2):
        print(f'{teams[0]} vs {teams[1]}')

main()
```

**Вывод**:

```
LBZS vs XERXIA
HR vs Nemiga
VP vs Entity
Keeper vs ALPHA
GG vs TSpirit
5RFS vs Dreamers
Balrogs vs CDUB
Saiyan vs TF
M11 vs Tsunami
iG.V vs PP
Balrogs vs Keeper
5RFS vs Qhali
ETERNITY vs ALPHA
Knights vs Mystique
ETERNITY vs 5RFS
PRX vs AnotherNA
Balrogs vs Dreamers
M11 vs Virgo
```